# Why does Xe have a higher boiling point than Ne?

Tags: intermolecular-forces, boiling-point

I am certain that the reason involves intermolecular forces, but since both $Xe$ and $Ne$ are noble and non-polar gases, shouldn't these forces have a much smaller effect or negligible on boiling point?

Comment: You'd be surprised, dispersion forces are *much* more important than high school chem makes them out to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main interaction between noble gases is Dispersion. (inert gas that's where the name comes from)
Dispersion is larger in heavier atoms. (Considerable larger, 18+18+8 more electrons difference is massive)

an example:
When Interaction energy passes zero point and thermal energy you can have the solid phase. This is why you will not have solid helium.